# Python 2.7 String Index Error

Tags: python, random

I'm writing a program to choose a random line from a text file using a while loop as a counter and then another variable to choose the random line:

```
import random 


fortunes_file = open("fortunes.txt", "r")


fortunes = fortunes_file.readline()

count = 0


while fortunes != "":
    count += 1
    fortunes = fortunes_file.readline()

rand_line = random.randint(1, count)

print fortunes[rand_line]

fortunes_file.close()
```

However, I get the following error when trying to run the program:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `readlines()` not `readline()`; but actually you can highly simplify your code:

```
import random

with open('fortunes.txt') as f:
   fortunes = list(f)

print(random.choice(fortunes))
```

Or, if you prefer the `readlines()` version:

```
import random

f = open('fortunes.txt')
fortunes = f.readlines()
f.close()

print(random.choice(fortunes))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting `fortunes` on each iteration of the `while` loop.
 At the EOF [`.readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) returns an empty string, therefore `fortunes[rand_line]` raises the `IndexError`. You could use [`.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) instead (or just use the file object as an iterator):

```
with open("fortunes.txt", "r") as fortunes_file:
    fortunes = fortunes_file.readlines()  # alternatively, use list(fortunes_file)
print(random.choice(fortunes))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
fortunes = fortunes_file.readline()

...

    fortunes = fortunes_file.readline()
```

You just re-defined the variable, so after that `while` loop end, `fortunes` actually is the last line in your file.

---

You can simply use [`io.IOBase.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) to read the file into a list line-by-line, and use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to choose an element in a list randomly. You don't need a counter and *slice the list* yourself.

For example:

```
import random   

# use `with` is recommended here since you don't need close the file manually
with open("fortunes.txt", "r") as f:
    fortunes = fortunes_file.readlinse()

print random.choice(fortunes)
```

---

However, if you also want to know how to *fix your code*, just put the output of [`io.IOBase.readline()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline) into a list like below:

```
import random 


fortunes_file = open("fortunes.txt", "r")    

fortunes = []
fortunes.append(fortunes_file.readline())   
count = 0


while fortunes != "":
    count += 1
    fortunes.append(fortunes_file.readline())

rand_line = random.randint(1, count)

print fortunes[rand_line]   
fortunes_file.close()
```

Note that if you don't want use `.readlines()` and `random.choice()`, you still don't need that counter, you can also use [`len(fortunes)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to get the length of your list instead of *write a useless counter yourself*.